# update the quantity without creating a new row with angular as simply as possible

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cart

I try to do a shopping cart each time I add the same item it creates a new line for me,
I would like to update the Quantity, do I have to make a loop that goes through an array?

**ts.file**

```
  productList = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Louis Vuis', price: 10, qtn: 1 },
    { id: 2, name: 'shubert helmet', price: 20, qtn: 1 },
  ];

  productArray: any = [];

  add(product) {
    this.productArray.push(product);
  }

  inc(added) {
    added.qtn = added.qtn + 1;
  }

  dec(added) {
    if (added.qtn != 1)
      added.qtn -= 1;
  }

  remove(id) {
    this.productArray.splice(id, 1);
  }
}
```

**html**

```
        <div class="card" *ngFor="let product of productList">
            <h1>{{product.name}}</h1>
            <p class="price">{{product.price | currency: 'USD'}}</p>
            <p><button (click)="add(product)">Add to Cart</button></p>

                        <th>product</th>
                        <th>price</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                        <th>total</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody *ngFor="let added of productArray">
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{added.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{added.price | currency: 'USD'}}</td>
                        <td class="increment">
                            <button (click)="dec(added)">-</button>
                            <span>{{added.qtn}}</span>
                            <button (click)="inc(added)">+</button>
                        </td>
                        <td (click)="remove()"><strong class="remove">X</strong></td>
```

Comment: Why? It seems your code works. what is your problem?

Comment: the problem is that each time I add the same item it creates a new line for me instead of updating the quantity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your `add(product)` to:

```
  add(product, idx) {
    const found = this.productArray.find(
      item => JSON.stringify(item) === JSON.stringify(product)
    );
    if (found) {
      this.productArray[idx].qtn++;
    } else {
      this.productArray.push(product);
    }
  }
```

Here it will search for a similar product (*I dont know which was the unicity criteria, so I compared the whole object with the whole new added one*), If it's found, it would update the quantity, else it push a new product.

And the HTML part:

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let product of productList; let idx = index"> // <-- here
    <h1>{{product.name}}</h1>
    <p class="price">{{product.price | currency: 'USD'}}</p>
    <p><button (click)="add(product, idx)">Add to Cart</button></p> // <-- & here
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-f7q96w?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Answer (score 0):

the issue coming from:

```
add(product) {
   this.productArray.push(product);
 }
```

you push the same item and create a new object in your array.
you can fix it by, checking if this item exist:

```
add(product) {
for(let singleProduct of productList){
  if(singleProduct.name === product.name){
   //here you want to only increase the quantity of this product
   //it will look like this:
   singleProduct.qtn += 1
  } else {
   productArray.push(product);
 }
    
}
```